# How to disable touchpad tapping when typing on keyboard?

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, kubuntu, touchpad

I used to have an option in settings in Kubuntu 10.10 to do this.
Now I cannot find it in 11.04.
Where can I find it ? or was it removed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the solution for the problem:

1. install kde-config-touchpad package.
2. Run Utilities->Touchpad Management and the application will have the option in GUI.

Comment: I see an option to disable the entire touchpad. How is just tapping disabled? (On kubuntu 11.10)

Comment: after install that package you can call the configuration panel with command *synaptiks* there is also a *synaptikscfg* for a command line config. The option in panel is called "Automatically switch off touchpad on keyboard activity"

Answer (score 7):

Direct link to the window manager-independent solution:
http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/ubuntu-automatically-disable-touchpad.html

Comment: More details at [ubuntuwiki.net](http://ubuntuwiki.net/index.php/Touchpad,_disabling_while_typing).

Comment: Avoid link-only solutions please, as links tend to rot with time.

Comment: (see my simple answer using the same tool)

Answer (score 0):

Use **synclient** (for Synaptic devices, i.e. most touchpads), which (as of 14.04) ships by default with Ubuntu:

```
$ synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

turns the touchpad off

```
$ synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

turns it back on.